# Combining list of data.tables based on data.table name

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, purrr

This is an extension to the question I posted a number of years ago: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236362/combining-multiple-data-tables-within-a-list-into-a-list-of-two-data-tables)

In summary, I have an indeterminate (in advance) number of data.tables in a list, some of which have duplicate names. I want to combine all data.tables with the same name using rbindlist, and fill any columns that don't have corresponding values with NA. i.e. use the 'fill = T' element of rbindlist.

I then want to return a list with the data.tables and name them based on their original names.

I'll give an example:

```
library(data.table)

# Create data for list A

A_1 <- data.table(A = 1:2,B = 2:3)
A_2 <- data.table(C = 100:102,D = 300:302,E = 1:3)
A <- list(AA = A_1,BB = A_2)

# Create data for list B

B_1 <- data.table(A = 2:4,B = 1:3,F = 4:6)
B_2 <- data.table(C = 10:12,D = 20:22,G = 1:3,I = 10:12)
B <- list(AA = B_1,BB = B_2)

# Create data for list C

C_1 <- data.table(I = 1:2,J = 3:4)
C_2 <- data.table(C = 1:3,D = 4:6)
C <- list(AA = C_1,BB = C_2)

# Create list DT which is a combination of lists A, B and C

DT <- c(A,B,C)
```

I can combine them easily enough using the following code.

```
library(purrr)

pmap(.l = list(y = unique(names(DT))),
     .f = function(y) rbindlist(DT[names(DT) %in% y],fill = T)) %>% 
          set_names(unique(names(DT)))
```

However, in practice, DT is formed by another function which I'd strongly prefer to simply chain (%>%) the result from that function output, and then jump straight into the pmap approach above without first 'creating' DT.

I've tried the following:

```
# As a substitute for the function code creating DT, I'll simply put DT itself below as 
# a representation of the output

DT %>% pmap(.l = list(y = unique(names(.))),
     .f = function(y) rbindlist(.[names(.) %in% y],fill = T))
```

This doesn't work and gives an error suggesting that there are unused elements of the function. Do you know why it doesn't work?

Note that I haven't then used 'set_names' to name the output from the pmap function, as the unique names of DT would have been 'forgotten' after creating the pmap output. I'm not sure how to use chains to do that (or if it's possible without including that output in the data.table output itself).

Let me know if this is unclear and I can try to explain it another way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could block it in braces (`{}`

```
library(purrr) # version 1.0.0
library(dplyr)
DT %>% {
     unq <- unique(names(.))
     pmap(.l = list(y = unq),
     .f = function(y) rbindlist(.[names(.) %in% y],fill = TRUE)) %>%
      setNames(unq)
  }
```

---

Or instead of looping over the names and do rbinding, `split` by names, which return a named list and then do the rbind

```
DT %>% 
  split(names(.)) %>% 
  map(list_rbind)
```

-output

```
$AA
    A  B  F  I  J
1:  1  2 NA NA NA
2:  2  3 NA NA NA
3:  2  1  4 NA NA
4:  3  2  5 NA NA
5:  4  3  6 NA NA
6: NA NA NA  1  3
7: NA NA NA  2  4

$BB
     C   D  E  G  I
1: 100 300  1 NA NA
2: 101 301  2 NA NA
3: 102 302  3 NA NA
4:  10  20 NA  1 10
5:  11  21 NA  2 11
6:  12  22 NA  3 12
7:   1   4 NA NA NA
8:   2   5 NA NA NA
9:   3   6 NA NA NA
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun.
I have a few questions:
1. Can you please explain how the use of the bracket works in your first approach?
2. In that first approach, is it then possible to extract the names 'AA' and 'BB' (in this example) to name the list output?
3. In the second approach, for some reason I'm seeing the following error when attempting to run it: 'Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object 'list_rbind' not found'. It seems to be from the "rlist" package which I've installed, so not sure what I'm doing wrong sorry.

Comment: @Phil The second approach fails probably because your `purrr` is not updated.  I used `purrr 1.0.0` where they mention `map_dfr` getting deprecated in favor or list_rbind.  YOu can also use `DT %>% 
  split(names(.)) %>% 
  map(bind_rows)`

Comment: @Phil For the first issue, it is because of lhs first argument.  If you check the documentation of `?"%>%"` - `It is perfectly valid to use the dot placeholder several times in the rhs call, but by design the behavior is slightly different when using it inside nested function calls. In particular, if the placeholder is only used in a nested function call, lhs will also be placed as the first argument! ... It is possible to overrule this behavior by enclosing the rhs in braces.`

Comment: @Phil You can extract by having multiple statements i.e. `DT%>%{unq <- unique(names(.));  pmap(.l = list(y =unq),
     .f = function(y) rbindlist(.[names(.) %in% y],fill = TRUE)) %>% setNames(unq)}`

Comment: Legend! Thanks so much for that. I'll have a look and get back to you with any further questions.